# Do I need to use Mono or Flux as return type of all methods from the Router to the Repository when working with Flux for propper reactive web service?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I want to develop a reactive web server application with Spring WebFlux so my backend can have the most efficient handling of multiple requests and the other benefits of the reactive programming, as they say that it can use one or few threads to handle a lot of requests from the client, different from the traditional Spring Web application that uses one thread for each request.

So let's say I have 3 layers on my architecture: The router and the handler (that would be my rest controllers), the service (that contains all the businesss logic) and the repository (that handles the access to the database).

I know my router and handler have to work with and return Mono/Flux to be reactive. But my question is: for my application to be fully reactive, do I need to work with and return Mono/Flux type all the way from the router and handler layer, to the service layer, to the repository layer? Or can my application still accomplish that by other means and use Mono/Flux only on the router and handler layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: I am only trying to explain you the concept. You may find more technical reasoning on other answers.

The idea behind writing any method as a reactive method is that its computation involves Thread waits, like a DB call or an HTTP request.
If your service method is expected to perform such operations where in you need not block your thread until you receive the data, you can write such operations in a reactive manner.

Now to answer your question, assuming you will be using a reactive DB library to make the DB call, your DAO will be returning an instance of `Mono<T>` or `Flux<T>`, that needs to be subscribed to and only then it would execute.

So ideally, YES, you should return the `Mono<T>` or `Flux<T>` instances back until your controller 
or you can call `.block()` which I would not recommend you to, since it would fail the purpose of writing the reactive code 
or `.subscribe()` that would execute the task in a separate Thread if you do not expect the results of this operation in current Thread like pushing a message to queue.